# update a field with different information

Tags: sql

```
SELECT clientLastName__c, clientFirstName__c, clientID__c, Category_ID__c, 
    ID AS Incident__c, OwnerId, SystemTypeDesc as taskDescription__c
FROM process.dbo.vw_NewHireProcess
WHERE System_Type__c IS NOT NULL`
```

I'm not sure how to update the OwnerId field with a specific value, but I don't want to change the name of the column.

Comment: Your example SQL is a `SELECT` not an `UPDATE` - is this what you wanted to show?

Comment: What you want `UPDATE` OR `SELECT`?

Comment: I'm assuming I can't do an update and a select in the same statement can I?

Comment: what error did you receive? Are you trying to update a view?

Comment: I did `95939439uuxx as OwnerId` but received an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: I wanted it a static owner id value

Comment: @Lisa: see my answer (first example) for a static value of OwnerId.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name.  I tried that but got the incorrect syntax error near the keyword as

Comment: @Lisa: my statement will definitely work. There must be something you are not telling us.

Comment: Here is my exact code:`select clientLastName__c, clientFirstName__c, clientID__c, Category_ID__c, ID AS Incident__c, 005300000052NwNAAU as OwnerId, SystemTypeDesc as taskDescription__c from process.dbo.vw_NewHireProcess Where System_Type__c IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Lisa -- You're soooooo close!  All you need to do is put 005300000052NwNAAU inside single quotes.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
select clientLastName__c, 
  clientFirstName__c, 
  clientID__c, 
  Category_ID__c, 
  ID AS Incident__c, 
  '95939439uuxx' AS OwnerId, 
  SystemTypeDesc as taskDescription__c 
from process.dbo.vw_NewHireProcess 
Where System_Type__c IS NOT NULL
```

Good luck!

Comment: I reformatted your code for readability, but the formatting isn't important.  What's important is that you can put a hardcoded value right in your query.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to alter the values, but this is the layout for an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE yourTableName
   SET OwnerId = yourValue
 WHERE yourWhereClause
```

Comment: can i do that within my select statement?

Comment: You can have a `SELECT` within an `UPDATE` but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change your column name. You can update like

```
UPDATE process.dbo.vw_NewHireProcess 
SET OwnerId = 'New Value whatever you want'  WHERE OwnerId = 'Current Value'
```

Comment: I don't think she wants to update the table... just to return a hardcoded value for OwnerID.

Comment: Yeah.  But I think it was just a mistake in her terminology.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return a constant value as the ownerid column, you can do the following:

```
select clientLastName__c, 
       clientFirstName__c, 
       clientID__c, 
       Category_ID__c, 
       ID AS Incident__c, 
       42 as OwnerId, 
       SystemTypeDesc as taskDescription__c 
from process.dbo.vw_NewHireProcess 
Where System_Type__c IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to return a different value for ownerId based on the value in that column you can do something like this:

```
select clientLastName__c, 
       clientFirstName__c, 
       clientID__c, 
       Category_ID__c, 
       ID AS Incident__c, 
       case 
         when OwnerId < 100 then -1
         when OwnerId >= 100 and ownerId < 1000 then 1
         else 42
       end as ownerId
       SystemTypeDesc as taskDescription__c 
from process.dbo.vw_NewHireProcess 
Where System_Type__c IS NOT NULL
```

But none of those will change the value that is *stored* in the database. It's merely a replacement while you select the values.